# Wordpress ACF php relationships

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I’ve spent all day reading forums & I’m struggling to come up with a solution to this problem.

I’ve got 2 custom post types:
People
Jobs

Using an ACF relationship, I’ve got a 2 way relationship field called Job Client (job_client) where we can link the related client/customer to the job.

What I’d like to display on the job page, is some basic information of the client that gets pulled from the People custom post type. Employer, contact details etc. These are setup as ACF fields.

So far I’ve got the following code. It displays the standard wordpress fields (title, permalink) fine, but I’m struggling with the ACF fields. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$job_client_connect = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'job_client', // name of custom field
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));

?>
<?php if( $job_client_connect ): ?>
    <table>
    <?php foreach( $job_client_connect as $job_client_connect ):?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $job_client_connect->ID ); ?>">
                    <?php echo get_the_title( $job_client_connect->ID ); ?>
                </a>
                <p><?php echo get_field('employer', $job_client_connect->ID ); ?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what kind of field is "employer"? Is it a text field?

Comment: No it's a relationship to a 'company' custom post type

Comment: In that case the return value of get_field wil be eigther an id or a post object, probably a post object. Try <?php $employer = get_field('employer', $job_client_connect->ID ); ?> and then <?php echo $employer->post_title; ?>

Comment: Yes it's a post object. That code doesn't return anything though

Comment: Ok. Can you confirm that there is a employer set for that person? And that "employer" is that actual field name? Also check that there isn't a second field with that name!? and what is the output of <?php var_dump( get_field('employer', $job_client_connect->ID ) ); ?>

Comment: Yes employer is set & isn't a duplicate. That code prints an array which is from the correct employer page - can't post on here it's too long

Comment: Ah, it seems relationship fields return a array of post objects; https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/ from my earlier answer try <?php echo $employer[0]->post_title; ?>

Comment: Yes that's solved it, thanks!
What is the significance of the [0]?

Comment: The relationship fields return a array of post objects. [0] gives you the first post object in the array. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: Perfect thanks - so if I wanted to print a different value, change the number accordingly?

Comment: $employer is a array of employer posts. So $employer[0] gives your the first post in the list. $employer[1] will giv you the second. If you want other values of the post object you can access them by there property name $employer[0]->post_content, $employer[0]->ID etc... You can <?php print_r($employer[0]); ?> for all the object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Full working code for anybody who may find this useful

```
<?php
$job_client_connect = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'people', // name of post type
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'job_client', // name of custom field
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));

?>

<?php if( $job_client_connect ): ?>
    <table>
    <?php foreach( $job_client_connect as $job_client_connect ):?>
        <?php $employer = get_field('employer', $job_client_connect->ID ); ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $job_client_connect->ID ); ?>">
                    <?php echo get_the_title( $job_client_connect->ID ); ?>
                </a>
                <p><?php echo $employer[0]->post_title; ?></p>



            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```